# How to display flashing message without reloading the page in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I'm working on a web application using Flask in Python.

I have small function in my application that calculates some values in the background and displays the result on the web page via a flashing message.

Everything is displaying and working fine but it requires page reloading to get the flashing message.

I want to display messages without reloading page.

I heard that I can do that with js, but I'm not familiar with js.

If you have any ideas or suggestion I would appreciate.

There is my code that could build a better picture of what I'm doing.

This is the renderer between my app and the main html file

```html
{% macro render_field(field) %}
 <dt> {{ field.label }}
 <dd> {{ field(**kwargs)|safe }}
 {% if field.errors %}
        <ul class=errors>
        {% for error in field.errors %}
                <li>{{ error }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
 {% endif %}
 </dd>
{% endmacro %}
```

This is the html file were I want to display flashing messages:

```html
<div class="container-fluid" style="min-height:100%">
  {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %} 
    {% if messages %} 
      {% for message in messages %}
      <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button> 
        {{message}}
      </div>
      {% endfor %} 
    {% endif %} 
  {% endwith %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 13):

Here's what [Flask Web Development: Developing Web Applications with Python (pp. 46-48)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449372627) has to say of *Message Flashing:*

Sometimes it is useful to give the user a status update after a request is completed. This
could be a confirmation message, a warning, or an error. A typical example is when you
submit a login form to a website with a mistake and the server responds by rendering
the login form again with a message above it that informs you that your username or
password is invalid.
Flask includes this functionality as a core feature. Example 4-6 shows how the `flash()`
function can be used for this purpose.

*Example 4-6. hello.py: Flashed messages*

```py
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = Nameform()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        old_name = session.get('name')
        if old_name is not None and old_name != form.name.data:
            flash('Looks like you have changed your name!')
        session['name'] = form.name.data
        form.name.data = ''
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('index.html', form=form, name=session.get('name'))
        form = form, name = session.get('name'))
```

In this example, each time a name is submitted it is compared against the name stored
in the user session, which would have been put there during a previous submission of
the same form. If the two names are different, the `flash()` function is invoked with a
message to be displayed on the next response sent back to the client.

Calling `flash()` is not enough to get messages displayed; the templates used by the
application need to render these messages. The best place to render flashed messages is
the base template, because that will enable these messages in all pages. Flask makes a
`get_flashed_messages()` function available to templates to retrieve the messages and
render them, as shown in Example 4-7.

*Example 4-7. templates/base.html: Flash message rendering*

```html
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    {% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
    <div class="alert alert-warning">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
        {{ message }}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}

    {% block page_content %}{% endblock %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

In this example, messages are rendered using Bootstrap’s alert CSS styles for warning
messages (one is shown in Figure 4-4).

[image: Figure 4-4. Flashed message]

*Figure 4-4. Flashed message*

A loop is used because there could be multiple messages queued for display, one for
each time `flash()` was called in the previous request cycle. Messages that are retrieved from `get_flashed_messages()` will not be returned the next time this function is called,
so flashed messages appear only once and are then discarded.

Comment: that is a good example but what to do if the message should be displayed without clicking the button? Because in my application i have a script that permorm some action with a face recognision camera and it suppose to dispay message such as user is recognized or not

Comment: @boardrider please don't use pictures in your post. Instead use the code feature on stack overflow. This is a great example of doing messages. I've already created something like this for my applications. My post is for *blinking* messages.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question concerns accessing flashed messages via AJAX. The asker just doesn't appear familiar with the term.

Comment: This does not address the question at hand

Answer (score 6):

This is not possible via Python without reloading the page. You must do this in javascript. I suggest CSS styling with `display: none` and `display: block`. Here is an example.

1) Python Code, this should go in your `app.py` or `flask.py` file.

```
app.route('/flash/<message>')
def flash(message):
  return render_template('flash.html', msg=message)
```

This will render the HTML page named `flash.html`. The URL passed in will also have another argument, `<message>` this is the message that will flash. A URL like this, `localhost:80/flash/Hello%20World!` will flash the message "Hello World!" on your screen.

There is also another way to pass a message in, this is will arguments. The code for that is like so.

```
app.route('/flash')
def flash():
  message = request.args.get("msg")
  return render_template("flash.html", ,msg=message)
```

This uses the flask's request arguments. So a URL like this, `localhost:80/flash?msg=Hello%20World!` will give a flashing message saying "Hello World!". If you want to use this method be sure to have the import statement, `from flask import request` in your import statements.

2) Html Code, this is a separate file named, `flash.html` in your templates folder.

```
<body>
  <h1 id="header">{{ message }}</h1>
  <script>
    var heading = $("#header");
    setInterval(function() {
      if (heading.style.display == "block") { heading.style.display = "none"; }
      else if (heading.style.display == "none") { heading.style.display = "block"; }
    }, 1000);
  </script>
</body>
```

The `1000` in the setInterval is milliseconds. So the heading will *blink* every 2 seconds.

Comment: As i understood in your example it has to return value to the function but what can i do if in my app i have to display message and continue reading the script? i cant just send variable into the function because it will execute function from the beggining

Comment: This will continue reading the script. `setInterval` is like a thread. I'm not sure how correct I am on this, but I do know that it will continue reading the script after the `setInterval` happens.

Comment: I'm sorry but how to you pass flash("text")  into the html template? do you pass it with variable ?

Comment: You example does not work for me at all. I copy your code but there is nothing happened

Comment: You must have the code correct in the `flask.py` file. The variable gets passed in as you render the template. The variable is passed through with `render_template` function. The variable can then be accessed in the flask code with `{{ variable }}`.

Comment: How do you pass flash message into there ? Could you please explain it to me. I would appreciate

Comment: In your example you do not pass any message. Right?

Comment: I made a few edits, including adding a method which has the arguments that you can pass in through a URL. I hope this help explain my examples. Also yes the URL does pass a message in; however, you can change this in whatever way you want it's just a variable local named `message`.

Comment: @trm0808 If you have fixed your problem please mark an answer correct so that others that look up this question have an answer. Or if you fixed it without these answers, post how you solved it in an answer by yourself.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to consider using [Toastr](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr) instead.  I ran into the same roadblock with Flask's Flash feature, and Toastr is pure JS.  You can use it just like a console log line in your code

`toastr.info("Here's a message to briefly show to your user");`

Comment: Excellent library for flashing

Answer (score 1):

```
**Display flash messages in python** 
    {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %} {% if
        messages %} {% for category, message in messages %} {% if category ==
        'error' %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger alter-dismissable fade show" role="alert">
          {{ message }}
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        {% else %}
        <div class="alert alert-success alter-dismissable fade show" role="alert">
          {{ message }}
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        {% endif %} {% endfor %} {% endif %} {% endwith %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not redirect if your form is not valid. Instead of that you can render the template again with the form filled in and errors showing either in the flash messages or form.

At the end you can not make it with pure Flask without reloading the page. But you can use a tiny ajax call for your purpose.

I leave a small example [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flask-form-submission-without-page-reload/) of how to do this.